# ngclass not updating when updating from another component

Tags: angular, angular7

child component html file

```
<div [ngClass]="wrp_cls"></div>
```

child component ts file

```
@Input() config: any = {};
  wrp_cls: any = [];

this.wrp_cls =[this.config.wrp_cls,'class1']
```

parent component

```
<child-component [config]="config"></child-component>
```

when I try to update a class from from parent component , the style is not being updated in child component ,

Comment: where do you use `this.wrp_cls =[this.config.wrp_cls,'class1']` ?

Comment: in child component <div [ngClass]="wrp_cls"></div>, it just array of styles

Comment: i mean where do you use it in the ts file of your child component (it must be part of a lifecycle hook or an function)

Comment: inside a ngoninit lifehook , is there any other possible way other other than using lifecycle hooks @GérômeGrignon

Comment: As you set it into ngOnInit, it's only called once : here is your problem.

Comment: can you suggest workaround method ? @GérômeGrignon , i dont want to use lifecycle hook

Comment: follow the @GaurangDhorda answer

Answer (score 3):

Complete Working example [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkk95x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Your parent.html

```
<button (click)="send()">Change Color </button>

<app-child [config]="config"></app-child>
```

Your parent.ts...

```
config;
  send(){
     this.config = true;
  }
```

Your Child.html...

```
 <p [ngClass]=" {'config' : classConfig} ">
      child works! 
 </p>
```

Your Child.ts...

```
classConfig;
 @Input('config') set config(value){
   this.classConfig = value;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below method;

`@Input() config: any = {};
  wrp_cls: any = [];`

`ngOnChanges() {
   this.wrp_cls =[this.config.wrp_cls,'class1']
}`

Angular calls its `ngOnChanges()` method whenever it detects changes to input properties of the component (or directive).

Comment: I want to avoid using lifecycle hook

Comment: Angular only calls the hook when the value of the input property changes, not on every change detection.

Comment: Any particular reason for avoiding the life-cycle hook?

Answer (score 0):

Placing code on the `ngOnInit` life cycle method, will execute it once.

if you wish to bind the child template value to the input value, using the default change detection, bind to the input value itself.

`<div [ngClass]="config.wrp_cls">child component html file</div>`

*forked GaurangDhorda's stackblitz example to create you a demo:

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztbflm?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

This will require no additional code changing on your part.